# Paypal IPN message queued

Tags: paypal-ipn

using IPN Simulator, my listener (in sandbox) is working fine.

then I submit the order by the html form.

I noticed that all the IPN messages were "queued" (from the IPN history)

what make this happen? And How can I solve this?

I read some old threads that same case was caused by Paypal Server. Can anyone help to advise on this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't happen often, but it could be that the IPN server is simply backed up so the IPNs are waiting in the queue and will be sent as soon as the servers catch up.

Another thing that could cause it, though, is if you have lots of failures happening with your IPN script.  In such cases PayPal may place you on a slower queue because they don't want to waste server resources if you're failing a lot.  You should get notifications about that if this sort of thing is happening, though, and eventually they would just turn IPN off altogether until you get it fixed and re-enable it.